# Из excel таблицы в бд Django

Tags: django, sqlite, excel

Есть excel таблица в которой есть куча строк с информацией про товары(запчасти). Есть форма загрузки файла, нужно сделать чтобы пользователь мог загрузить excel таблицу и информация из неё перенеслась в бд.
Прошерстил 10 страниц в гугле - ничего не нашёл.

Comment: берете и пишете парсер/импорт из excel

Comment: можно конвертировать в `csv` и воспользоваться стандартной одноименной библиотекой. либо любая либа для работы с `xls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты можешь после сохранения файла открывать его с помощью [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Читаешь данные, дальше создаешь объекты и сохраняешь в базе.